# Identify duplicate search results, which are displayed in multiple pages

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to this forum as well as to Selenium. Please help me with the following issue:

1. I would like to compare the search results of a shopping site, which are displayed in multiple pages. I wanted to ensure that my search string results are only unique values.
2. When I try to print the search results that are displayed in the first page, it results 264 items; While it has only 60 items listed on the first page.
3. Some of the products displayed in the page are not printed, rather some items which are not visible in application are getting printed. I really doubt if it's considering disabled div tags as well.

In the below html, the div tag `class="block-grid-xs-3 hide-xs hide-sm hide-md hide-xl hide-tv prolist-row pb-xs-1-5"` is in "disabled" state, likewise there are many disabled tags available in this HTML code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 pl-xs-1 pl-md-3">
<div class="clearfix pb-xs-1-5">
<h2 class="screen-reader-only">Search results</h2>
<div class="block-grid-xs-2 hide-lg hide-xl hide-tv prolist-row pb-xs-1-5" data-behat-search-results-ads-xs="">
<div class="block-grid-xs-3 hide-xs hide-sm hide-md hide-xl hide-tv prolist-row pb-xs-1-5" data-behat-search-results-ads-lg="">
<div class="js-merch-stash-check-listing block-grid-item v2-listing-card position-relative " data-palette-listing-id="548623069" data-shop-id="" data-listing-id="548623069" data-behat-listing-card="">
<a class="prolist display-inline-block listing-link logged" data-listing-id="548623069" data-palette-listing-image="" href="https://www.etsy.com/listing/548623069/elegant-ivory-flower-girl-dressivory?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=flower girl dress&ref=sc_gallery-1-1&plkey=5dd934ef34daf3e1dfec620406d1cf14b94e9cf8:548623069" data-display-loc="w.0" data-page-num="1" data-position-num="1" data-logging-key="5dd934ef34daf3e1dfec620406d1cf14b94e9cf8:548623069" data-behat-search-ad-link="" title="elegant ivory flower girl dress,ivory flower girl dress,white flower girl dress,rustic flower girl dress,tutu flower girl dress">
<div class="v2-listing-card__img overflow-hidden mb-xs-1 position-relative">
<div class="v2-listing-card__info">
<p class="text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body"> elegant ivory flower girl dress,ivory flower girl dress,white flower girl dress,rustic flower girl dress,tutu flower girl dress </p>
<div class="v2-listing-card__shop">
<p class="n-listing-card__price text-gray strong mt-xs-0">
</div>
</a>
<div class="v2-listing-card__actions z-index-1 position-absolute">
</div>
<div class="js-merch-stash-check-listing block-grid-item v2-listing-card position-relative " data-palette-listing-id="206144142" data-shop-id="" data-listing-id="206144142" data-behat-listing-card="">
<div class="js-merch-stash-check-listing block-grid-item v2-listing-card position-relative " data-palette-listing-id="523280690" data-shop-id="" data-listing-id="523280690" data-behat-listing-card="">
</div>
<div class="block-grid-xs-4 hide-xs hide-sm hide-md hide-lg prolist-row pb-xs-1-5" data-behat-search-results-ads-xl="">
<div class="js-merch-stash-check-listing block-grid-item v2-listing-card position-relative " data-palette-listing-id="548623069" data-shop-id="" data-listing-id="548623069" data-behat-listing-card="">
<a class="prolist display-inline-block listing-link logged" data-listing-id="548623069" data-palette-listing-image="" href="https://www.etsy.com/listing/548623069/elegant-ivory-flower-girl-dressivory?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=flower girl dress&ref=sc_gallery-1-1&plkey=5dd934ef34daf3e1dfec620406d1cf14b94e9cf8:548623069" data-display-loc="w.0" data-page-num="1" data-position-num="1" data-logging-key="5dd934ef34daf3e1dfec620406d1cf14b94e9cf8:548623069" data-behat-search-ad-link="" title="elegant ivory flower girl dress,ivory flower girl dress,white flower girl dress,rustic flower girl dress,tutu flower girl dress">
<div class="v2-listing-card__img overflow-hidden mb-xs-1 position-relative">
<div class="v2-listing-card__info">
<p class="text-gray text-truncate mb-xs-0 text-body" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"> elegant ivory flower girl dress,ivory flower girl dress,white flower girl dress,rustic flower girl dress,tutu flower girl dress </p>
<div class="v2-listing-card__shop">
<p class="n-listing-card__price text-gray strong mt-xs-0">
</div>
</a>
```

This is my code, to find and print the items in the first page:

```
List<WebElement> searchres=d.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.v2-listing-card__info>p"));
int o=0;
String b[]=new String[searchres.size()];
for(WebElement h: searchres )
    {
        b[o]=h.getText().trim();
        System.out.println(h.getText());
        o++;
    }

HashMap <Integer, String> map= new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(b[i]))
        {
            System.out.println("duplicate");
        }

        map.put(i,b[i]);            
    }
```

Comment: The first `for` loop seems redundant. Other than that, you need to test some more readings in order to come up with a solution, or at least with a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: Please post a link to the site and explain in a little more detail what exactly you are looking to print. What does `I wanted to ensure that my search string results are only unique values.` mean? The URL for each result is unique or ?

Comment: I'm just testing some random shopping site..i'm inputting some keyword in search box in etsy.com and it gives me 250 page results. now i have to ensure whether all the search results in 250 pages are unique(means no product is repeated).Right now i'm able to successfully compare the items in a single page , but i have to compare this with all the 250 pages. What is the approach needs to be followed here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to find all "p" elements in div with class "v2-listing-card__info", and because there are several p elements in divs, you have more results, than needed.

Comment: okay..will put someother parameter and try again..how about comparing search results from different pages to find the unique ones..is there any approach..

Comment: You want to get results from 2 pages and leave only unique ones among them?
You may use arrays for that

Comment: You want to get results from 2 pages and leave only unique ones among them?
You may use arrays for that

IWebElement[] page1 = driver.FindElements(By.Whatever).ToArray();
Go to page 2
IWebElement[] page2 = driver.FindElements(By.Whatever).ToArray();

foreach(IWebElement q in page1)
{
    foreach(IWebElement w in page2)
    {
         if(q.text == w.text)
         {
              page1 = RemoveFromArray(page1, q);
              page2 = RemoveFromArray(page2, w);
              break;
         }
    }
}